# Cannot sign into iCloud on Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: icloud, mojave, apple-id, system-settings

I can sign into iCloud on my iPhone, iPad, and even the appstore on my Mac. But not through the Mac system preferences. Not the iCloud preferences nor Internet Accounts. I type in my Apple ID and (correct) password, and after watching a spinning loading icon for a few seconds, I'm brought back to an empty Apple ID field, with no error message.

I tried:

> sudo -v ; killall -9 accountsd com.apple.iCloudHelper ; defaults delete MobileMeAccounts ; mkdir ~/Library/Accounts/Backup ; mv ~/Library/Accounts/*.sqlite* ~/Library/Accounts/Backup/ ; killall -9 accountsd com.apple.iCloudHelper ; sudo reboot

which did not work. I tried temporarily moving

> ~/Library/Accounts/Application\ Support/iCloud

and the system seems to never generate any new contents.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try a safe mode boot? Hold shift while cold booting. Then reboot normally and try again. System caches are flushed when you safe boot.

Comment: @JamesBrickley No change